# JSONB Postgresql - How to update array attribute in a nested object?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jsonb

I need to update an array in jsonb postgresql in nested object. I can't seem to have this working. I have tried many different things so far without success. I am trying to update the cleaner array by comparing with the schedule id.

**table**

```
id(serial) | info(jsonb)
```

**server.js**

```
var contractorInfo = {
    "id": cleanerid,
    "fname": fname,
    "lname": lname,
    "avatar":avatar
  }

//id
var laveid = 'order_cbs1l';
```

**Returns null doesn't update**

```
"UPDATE users SET info = JSONB_SET(info, '{schedule,cleaner}', '"+JSON.stringify(contractorInfo)+"') WHERE info->'schedule'->>'id'='"+laveid+"' RETURNING*"
```

**Returns null doesn't update**

```
"UPDATE users SET info = JSONB_SET(info, '{schedule,cleaner}', '"+JSON.stringify(contractorInfo)+"') WHERE info #>> '{schedule,id}' = '"+laveid+"' RETURNING*"
```

**json object**

```
{
  "dob": "1988-12-11",
  "type": "seller",
  "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
  "phone": "5553766962",
  "avatar": "image.png",
  "schedule": [
    {
      "id": "order_cbs1l",
      "pay": "230",
      "date": "2022-12-29",
      "status": "Available",
      "address": "234 Eleventh Street, Mildura Victoria 3500, Australia",
      "cleaner": {
        "id": "",
        "fname": "",
        "lname": "",
        "avatar": ""
      },
      "end_time": "10:15",
      "start_time": "01:00",
      "total_hours": "33300000",
      "paymentIntentId": "pi_3KJnrEFzZWeJoxzV1yUdGLQ8"
    }
  ],
  "last_name": "doe",
  "first_name": "john",
  "countrycode": "Canada: +1",
  "countryflag": "iti__ca",
  "date_created": "2022-11-12T19:44:36.714Z"
}
```

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL injections! Stop using string concatenation and [use a parameterised query](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query) instead.

Comment: You'll need to use `SET info = JSONB_SET(info, '{schedule,0,cleaner}', $2) WHERE info->'schedule'->0->>'id'=$1` if you want to test and update the first object in the array. What do you want to do if the array is empty or has multiple members?

Comment: I get this error with your codes : error: invalid input syntax for type json. detail: 'Token "order_cbs1l" is invalid.'  where: 'JSON data, line 1: order_cbs1l'... So I tried to solve this with JSON.stringify(laveid) but JSON.stringify adds double quotes around the value and so the program cannot find it. order_cbs1l !== "order_cbs1l"

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I can see is that your where class does not match the row in question. Since "schedule" is an array you should substitute

```
WHERE info->'schedule'->>'id'='"+laveid+"'
```

for

```
WHERE info->'schedule'-> 0 ->>'id'='"+laveid+"'
```

since this would reference the first element in the "schedule" array. Since the array only has one element you might also want to consider removing the array altogether by storing the json as

```
{
  "dob": "1988-12-11",
  "type": "seller",
  "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
  "phone": "5553766962",
  "avatar": "image.png",
  "schedule": {
    "id": "order_cbs1l",
    "pay": "230",
    "date": "2022-12-29",
    "status": "Available",
    "address": "234 Eleventh Street, Mildura Victoria 3500, Australia",
    "cleaner": {
      "id": "",
      "fname": "",
      "lname": "",
      "avatar": ""
    },
    "end_time": "10:15",
    "start_time": "01:00",
    "total_hours": "33300000",
    "paymentIntentId": "pi_3KJnrEFzZWeJoxzV1yUdGLQ8"
  },
  "last_name": "doe",
  "first_name": "john",
  "countrycode": "Canada: +1",
  "countryflag": "iti__ca",
  "date_created": "2022-11-12T19:44:36.714Z"
}
```

In which case the original where clause would work.