# Node-PostgreSQL JSONB : How to fix Invalid input syntax for type json Token is invalid error?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jsonb

I've got a parameterized query using Node server side to do operations on a Postgresql database. When I try to update the table, I get following error

> error: invalid input syntax for type json. detail: 'Token
> "order_cbs1l" is invalid.' where: 'JSON data, line 1: order_cbs1l'

I tried to solve this with `JSON.stringify(laveid)` but problem is that `JSON.stringify()` adds double quotes around the value and so to the logic of the program `order_cbs1l !== "order_cbs1l"`. The program cannot find a match if one value has double quotes and the other does not. Is there a solution for this?

**table**

```
id(serial) | info(jsonb)
```

**server.js**

```
var contractorInfo = {
    "id": cleanerid,
    "fname": fname,
    "lname": lname,
    "avatar":avatar
  }

  //stringify array
var cleaner = JSON.stringify(contractorInfo);

//id
var laveid = 'order_cbs1l';


//query
var text02 ="UPDATE users SET info = JSONB_SET(info, '{schedule,0,cleaner}', $2) WHERE info->'schedule'->0->>'id'=$1 RETURNING*";
var value02 = [cleaner,laveid];

//pool
[...]
```

### UPDATE

Here I'm adding the row from the database.

**json object**

```
{
  "dob": "1988-12-11",
  "type": "seller",
  "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
  "phone": "5553766962",
  "avatar": "image.png",
  "schedule": [
    {
      "id": "order_cbs1l",
      "pay": "230",
      "date": "2022-12-29",
      "status": "Available",
      "address": "234 Eleventh Street, Mildura Victoria 3500, Australia",
      "cleaner": {
        "id": "",
        "fname": "",
        "lname": "",
        "avatar": ""
      },
      "end_time": "10:15",
      "start_time": "01:00",
      "total_hours": "33300000",
      "paymentIntentId": "pi_3KJnrEFzZWeJoxzV1yUdGLQ8"
    }
  ],
  "last_name": "doe",
  "first_name": "john",
  "countrycode": "Canada: +1",
  "countryflag": "iti__ca",
  "date_created": "2022-11-12T19:44:36.714Z"
}
```

Comment: Seems you flipped the parameters. `laveId` should come first (`$1`), `cleaner` should come second (`$2`).

Comment: @Bergi : Good catch! I flipped them and no more error. But it's not returning anything returns empty [] and in the db; nothing is updated. Any idea?

Comment: Looks like `WHERE info->'schedule'->0->>'id' = 'order_cbs1l'` matches no rows in your table. I can't tell why that might be.

Comment: @Bergi: let me update with the object from the db.It is there.

Comment: How do you know that object exists in the database? Did you find that row using `SELECT * FROM users WHERE info->'schedule'->0->>'id' = 'order_cbs1l'`? How about `SELECT * FROM users WHERE info->'schedule'->0->>'id' = $1`?

Comment: @Bergi: it's very bizarre because no matter what I try the SELECT and/or UPDATE returns null despite the value existing in my table. I'm checking in the database and yes it is there. Strange behavior. I've been going over possible problems and solutions for the past hours. Scratching my head!

Comment: "*I'm checking in the database*" - how do you do that? Are you sure you're connected to the same database? Using the same role?

Comment: @Bergi : I've built an app.Everything else works well at fetching and updating data  back and fourth. So yes everything is connected to the same DB and same role. It's a software. And if I go check in the PgAdmin UI on the web, I can see the data is there.

Comment: @Bergi: Its got to be the wrong query. Am I right? Else why would it return [ ] every time?

Comment: @Bergi : WHERE info->'schedule'->1->>'id' = 'order_cbs1l' works. Does this mean I have to manually enter the position of the array in the object I want to fetch or update? This is not proficient... If the user has 100 appointments inside schedule... Everything needs to be dynamic!

Comment: That's weird, [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) state "*array elements are indexed from zero*" so `->0` really should have matched the object from your question.

Comment: "*Does this mean I have to manually enter the position of the array in the object I want to fetch or update? Everything needs to be dynamic!*" - that's why on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74945015/jsonb-postgresql-how-to-update-array-attribute-in-a-nested-object#comment132256424_74945015) I commented, asking what should happen the array is empty or has multiple members! Also which of the array elements will you want to update if they have multiple schedules?! While there are solutions to do this in JSON, you really should consider normalising your schema.

Comment: @Bergi: I found a way around this. My strategy is to send the array position from client when iterating. It works 100% of the time so that's good for me. Curious. How would you have solved it?

Comment: There's various ways to update nested arrays (with subqueries, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60115303/1048572)), but I would probably have normalised the database schema instead and stores a user's schedules in a separate table

Answer (score -1):

I think you need single quotes around the `$2` parameter.

```
var text02 ="UPDATE users SET info = JSONB_SET(info, '{schedule,0,cleaner}', '$2') WHERE info->'schedule'->0->>'id'=$1 RETURNING*";
```